# Installing Flutter

Tags: macos, flutter

I'm using Mac OS BigSur (11.1) and trying to install Flutter.  I am running into an issue where it just doesnt seem to load.  Has anyone got an idea where I am going wrong?  I've followed the instructions on loading and when I try to confirm it I get the following report in Terminal.

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
JonSinclair:~ JonSinclair$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:Users/JonSinclair/Developer/flutter/bin
JonSinclair:~ JonSinclair$ which flutter
JonSinclair:~ JonSinclair$ flutter --version
-bash: flutter: command not found
JonSinclair:~ JonSinclair$

Comment: Can you add an error to the question?

Comment: The error is that is says command not found, I would expect that it should show the flutter version

Comment: Maybe your path is wrong

Comment: You also need to update your .zprofile file because **PATH** gets reset when you close the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

To run flutter command in your terminal, you need to add it to your PATH. PATHs in zsh terminal are reset after you quit terminal. To make permanent changes to your PATH, you need to edit your .zprofile file. Let `~Desktop/Development/flutter` be your flutter installation directory.

Step 1 is to open .zprofile file
`cd && touch .zprofile && open .zprofile`

Now that your .zprofile is open, add this line at the very end of the file
`export PATH="$HOME/Desktop/Development/flutter/bin:$PATH";`

Save and close the file and run the command
`flutter doctor`

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I tried to follow you instructions and it didnt work - when I open the zprofile  its blank and so added the line - is that correct?

Comment: I don't know @Jon why it's blank but you can try adding `export PATH=".."` line and then check if it works.